# WAS 6.1 custom user roles

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

Instead of the already provided user roles in WAS 6.1, we want to customize it further. i.e, whether a user has permissions to deploy an EAR, change the configurations, Start / Stop the applications etc.

Is there any way to do this in WAS 6.1?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [preconfigured roles](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/rsec_adminroles.html) to accomplish this. However if you require more granularity or more options that will not be possible.